Фейковые имена пользователя в строке "печатает" Telegramm
В чате телеграмма появился человек, который через бота вписывает в строку "печатает" разные скажем так гадости. Выглядит это к примеру так "уродина печатает..."
Это самый приличный пример)
Нюанс еще в том, что у пользователей это "печатает..." различается.
Каждый видит что-то именно про себя. Предположу что идет привязка через айди.
Может кто-то подсказать, как это реализуют, и что можно с этим сделать?
Возможно я не по адресу, но решил попробовать спросить тут. Может какой-то совет дадите.

Первое, что приходит на ум - удалить бота из переписки :-)

А в участниках бота и не видно этого.

Ну, ещё можно попробовать в настройках скрыть всё, что можно скрыть. Тогда бот, возможно, не сможет идентифицировать пользователей. Но лучше в поддержку написать. Там люди более прошаренные ((чем я))
